# gogo shell doesn't work apache felix 6.0.3?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am learning osgi, and I installed apache felix (6.0.3), when I executed the following command.

```
java -jar felix.jar
```

Felix doesn't display the shell gogo,and I don't know why ?

Answer (score 2):

OSGi is a modular system. You've just started the framework. The framework does not have any behavior, as it should. You need to install *bundles* to get any behavior. This includes the shell.

I've written an OSGi Starter based on gogo & Bndtools. You can find it here:

> https://bndtools.org/workspace/osgi-starter.html

Answer (score 1):

The gogo shell is implemented in separate bundles. You only start the framework without any bundles.

I propose a tooling like bnd to set up felix with the required bundles. See my [osgi ds hello world example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-ds-hello-world). It starts the shell and also shows how you can build and deploy your own code.